# Image is not displayed in pyside exe file by py2exe

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, py2exe

I have some images in pyside dsktop application in **resources** **folder.** Here the setup.py file to make a exe file.(python setup.py py2exe)

The exe file works perfect, just image is not displaying. Is there any mistake in setup.py file?

```
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import py2exe

from distutils.filelist import findall
import matplotlib
import cv2
import numpy
import os

datafiles = [
        ("resources", glob('resources/*.*'))
]


datafiles.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())


setup(
        console=['mainwindow.py'],
        #'file_resources': [bitmap_string[:-1]],

        options = {
                    'py2exe': {
                    'packages' : ['matplotlib'],
                    'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 
                                     'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 
                                     'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll'],
                    r'includes': [r'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                                  r'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx']
                                }
                    },
        zipfile = None,
        windows = [{
                    "script":"mainwindow.py",
                    "icon_resources":[(1, "tfr.ico")],

                    }],
        data_files = datafiles,
        )
```

I also tried following options in setup.py file.

"compressed": 2,
"optimize": 2,
"bundle_files": 1,

Comment: So are the images copied to the resources folder where the build resides? Did you solve the issue in the mean time?

Comment: Yes, I have solved the issue. I will write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added

```
datafiles.append(('imageformats', [
                'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll'
                ]))
```

in setup.py.

It will include qjpeg dll file which is necesary to display image file in exe.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import py2exe

from distutils.filelist import findall
import matplotlib
import cv2
import numpy
import os

datafiles = [
        ("resources", glob('resources/*.*'))
]

**datafiles.append(('imageformats', [
                'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll'
                ]))**

datafiles.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())


setup(
        console=['mainwindow.py'],
        #'file_resources': [bitmap_string[:-1]],

        options = {
                    'py2exe': {
                    'packages' : ['matplotlib'],
                    'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 
                                     'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 
                                     'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll'],
                    r'includes': [r'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                                  r'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx']
                                }
                    },
        zipfile = None,
        windows = [{
                    "script":"mainwindow.py",
                    "icon_resources":[(1, "tfr.ico")],

                    }],
        data_files = datafiles,
        )
```